# Tips to Remove Kitchen Cabinets and Countertops without Damage for Donation?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters

We're taking on a project to upgrade our kitchen cabinets and countertops, but we think that the current cabinets are quite new and usable (just not our style).  We'd like to remove them while minimizing the damage so that they retain their value when we donate them.  Any tips/info on how to do this?

Any ideas on the best places to donate kitchen cabinets would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, take off all the doors, drawers and counter tops. Many times, counter tops are glued to your base cabinets, and are bolted together at the seams with pocket bolts. Try to take these off carefully if you plan on re-using them, or donating them too.

Then, look for a board near the top of the base cabinets, this is the board usually used to screw the cabinets to the wall. Take the screws out that are being used to secure them to the wall, and it's likely that they'll can just be pulled away from the wall. Be careful though, sometimes, the base cabinets are screwed to each other too, so look at the insides of the base cabinets to see.

The same basic process can be done for the upper cabinets as well, except that you should make sure that they are not screwed to each other before trying to take one down. This is almost always a two-man job.

As for donations, I suggest looking for a Re-Store in your area. They are operated by Habitat For Humanity, and I personally have purchased many things (including cabinets) from them. All the proceeds from the sales of donated items goes to help low-income families earn the pride of home ownership!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, any idea if they would be willing to assist in the removal as well?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it depends the availability of volunteers in your area. Most will off free pick-up if it's available.

Comment: Attaboy up vote for the Re-Store / Habitat for Humanity comment.

Answer (score 4):

The local Habitat for Humanity might have a ReStore that accepts these donations. They may even help you with the removal.

Disclaimer, I'm a regular volunteer with my local Habitat chapter, but I'm not in any way paid by them.

Comment: Another attaboy up vote for the Re-Store / Habitat for Humanity comment